# Django Sending Nav Pill Selection

Tags: python, html, django, nav

I have two pills here:
[image]

I just want to be able to click on them and have a variable be sent to my 'views' code to tell me which one is selected.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="col-md-2" id = "charts_tables">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id = charts_tables>
            <li {% if type_display == 'charts' %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="" name = "radio-option" class="text-primary" {{type_display}} == 'charts'><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bolt"></i> Charts</a></li>
            <li {% if type_display == 'tables' %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="" name = "radio-option" class="text-primary" {{type_display}} == 'tables'><i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar"></i> Tables</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Ideally, when pushed I'd like to set the "type_display" variable to the name of the selected pill and pass that variable to my view file. I tried to make a similar post, but the only answer I receieved was to use radio buttons. For this project it has to be nav pills.

Here's the top of my view:

```
def analysis_view(request, action=None):
     print(request.GET.get("radio-option"))
```

I've been trying to find documentation for the past two days and nothing. I don't even see a nav-pills widget type in any docs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I've read your question five times and I still can't figure out what you want.

Comment: I want to know which nav pill is being pressed.